# Convert image to variable number of grayscales

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-filters

I want to convert an image to a variable number of grayscales, the number which is to be configurable by the user, ranging from 2 (monochrome/black and white) to 256 (full grayscale).

I've tried to accomplish this with both css and svg filters, e.g. in CSS:

```
filter: grayscale(100%)
```

converts an image to grayscales, which is what I'd want for 256 grayscales but other values like

```
filter: grayscale(10%)
```

do not limit the number of grayscales, but only reduce the number of colors used in the picture, so I can never get a monochrome result using these filters.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may first get the image and then draw it on a canvas and access it's pixels' RGB values one by one. Then the Y (luminance) will be calcaulted  with the formula `Y = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B` and insert the calculated Y back into the places of R, G and B per pixel.

Comment: For future reference, this technique you're trying to achieve is called "quantization" as outlined in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an SVG filter, but you are limited to a maximum of 64 values in Internet Explorer. The filter for a straight black/white posterize is this:

```
<filter id="greyscale-posterize" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
  <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
  <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

The filter for a ten value greyscale would be:

```
<filter id="greyscale-posterize" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1"/>
  <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1"/>
  <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

Use JavaScript to write in the appropriate number of ranges as the input is changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the type of solution I was hoping for! I've done as you suggested and modify the tableValues using JavaScript, the filter is applied to the image using CSS. This works flawlessly in Chrome, however, it does nothing in Firefox.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'm guessing it's a prefix problem. Firefox uses the unprefixed filter (there is no -moz-filter in Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

1. drawing the `<image>` or  `<svg>` to a canvas
2. reducing the canvas image data to grayscale by combining each color channel weighted by a visually appealing factor
3. reducing the number of colors by rounding to the nearest color in `[0, 255/(n-1), 255/(n-2), ..., 255]`
4. writing the canvas image data back to an `<image>` if needed.

```js
function rgbaToNGrayscales(src, numScales) {
  var d = (numScales - 1) / 255,
      inv_d = 1 / d,
      round = Math.round;
  for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i += 4) {
    src[i] = src[i + 1] = src[i + 2] = round(((src[i] * 4899 + src[i + 1] * 9617 + src[i + 2] * 1868 + 8192) >> 14) * d) * inv_d;
  }
}

var source = document.getElementById("source");
var target = document.getElementById("target");
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

slider.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = source.width;
  canvas.height = source.height;
  context.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  rgbaToNGrayscales(imageData.data, slider.value);
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  target.src = canvas.toDataURL();
});
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0">
<image id="source" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="http://cors.io?u=https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTjOI.png">
<image id="target">
```

This algorithm is very fast, but the resulting image might have less than the specified number of colors if there is no color in the original image falling in one of the specified color ranges. In this case, you would need a [more advanced color quantization algorithm such as median cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849115/image-palette-reduction/3849154#3849154).

Depending on your needs, attach a resize-listener to your `<svg>` and overlay it dynamically with a canvas element of the respective dimensions displaying the resulting grayscale image.

The sample picture:

[image: Sample picture]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, too. I was hoping to avoid having to do everything by hand in JavaScript, but this is probably the less browser-dependent solution.